# guava CacheBuilder performance

Tags: java, guava

The following micro benchmark uses Guava CacheBuilder.  It performs 1 magnitude times slower than ConcurrentHashMap.  Am I using CacheBuilder correctly?

```
    final Cache c = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().concurrencyLevel(10).maximumSize(100).build();
    int num = 10;
    final java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch startSignal = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(1);
    final java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch doneSignal = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(num);
    int j = 0;
    final Long[] pairs = new Long[] { new Long(5),
            new Long(324235342L), new Long(3242385842L), new Long(8463242363642L),
            new Long(3244532342L), new Long(54654L), new Long(7332742342L),
            new Long(32425345342L), new Long(32453662342L), new Long(63573242342L) };
    Object state = new Object();

    for (Long p : pairs) {
        c.put(p, state);
    }
    Thread [] threads = new Thread[num];
    for (int k = 0 ; k < num ; ++k) {
        final int z = k;
        threads[k] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            int i = z;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startSignal.await();
                    for (int j = 0 ; j < 100000 ; ++j) {
                        c.getIfPresent(pairs[z]);
                    }
                    doneSignal.countDown();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        t.start();
    }
    startSignal.countDown();
    c.getIfPresent(pairs[1]);
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    doneSignal.await();
    System.out.println("done in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
```

ConcurrentHashMap gives me 9 ms.  CacheBuilder gives me 90 ms.  This is after looping the same code for several minutes.

Comment: I don't find these results _terribly_ surprising?  `CacheBuilder` pays a price for features like `maximumSize` which you can't even emulate in a `ConcurrentHashMap`, even if it tries to minimize the overhead of those features.  If you didn't use `maximumSize` it'd probably be a fairer comparison.

Comment: Advice: You don't have to write `new Long(8463242363642L)` etc. - just literals, i.e. `8463242363642L`, and let Java do auto-boxing.

Comment: @louis-wasserman Removing `maximumSize` gives me slightly better performance. 25 ms vs 8 ms (`ConcurrentHashMap`)

Comment: Why does this concern you? If you only need a `ConcurrentHashMap`, use that. If you need `Cache` or `LoadingCache`'s additional functionality you're obviously also accepting the extra costs. The Guava folks have put a *lot* of work into benchmarking this stuff to ensure its performs well so that you don't have to worry about it.